# mod rewrite question mark and ampersands

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

The first GET argument should have a `?`. When i try this url i'm not able to `$_GET['type']`

```
http://localhost/category/general?type=pages&v=1
```

it only works with an `&`, when i use `$_GET['type']` i get `pages`

```
http://localhost/category/general&type=pages&v=1
```

Here is my mod rewrite..

```
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(\?type=[A-Za-z0-9-]+)?([^.]+)?/?$ /category.php?c=$1&type=$2&query=$3 [L]
```

How do i solve this so this url `http://localhost/category/general?type=pages&v=1` allows me to `$_GET['type']` with `pages` as the result?

Comment: Your second URL is incorrect. `&` only starts working **AFTER** a `?`. The url should be `http://localhost/category/general?type=pages&v=1`

Comment: thats exactly what i said.. i can't `$_GET['type']` with that url.

Comment: not sure why you're using rewrites anyways, other than to strip off the `.php` portion, everything else in the url could simply be handled by adding a `QSA` directive .

Comment: Could i have an example?.  i thought i need rewrites to create a pretty url like `localhost/category/general/topics`

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that in your `RewriteRule` you're trying to match a part of the query string, which isn't possible.

If I understand your problem correctly, you want requests to `http://example.com/category/general?type=pages&v=1` to be interpreted by the server as `http://example.com/category.php?c=general&type=pages&query=1`?

To match a query string, you need to prefix your rule with a condition.  The following should work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} type=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} v=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+) /category.php?c=$1&type=%1&query=%2
```

The first two lines are pre-conditions that state that the requested URL needs to have both `type=` and `v=` as part of the query string.  The final line rewrites the request.  This means that the URL will only be rewritten if it conforms to: `category/SOMETHING?type=SOMETHING&v=SOMETHING`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing RewriteRule with this one:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)(&.+)$ /category.php?c=$1$2 [L,NC]
```

This will make all of your `$_GET` variables available to `category.php`

e.g. for you URI of: `http://localhost/category/general&type=pages&v=1` this solution will give following query string:

```
$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"] = 'c=general&type=pages&v=1'
```